# How can I remove duplicates in SQL but keep one copy?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL with lines of an order as follows:

```
RowId     OrderId     Type     Text
----------------------------------------
 1        1           5        "Sometext"
 2        1           5        "Sometext"
 3        2           4        "Sometext"
 4        3           5        "Sometext"
 5        2           4        "Sometext"
 6        1           3        "Sometext"
```

**Each order cannot have a duplicate type, but can have multiple different types.**

Rows 1 and 2 are duplicates for Order **1**, but row 6 is fine.

Rows 3 and 5 are duplicates for Order **2**.

I need to delete all of the duplicated data, so in this case I need to delete **row 2 and row 5**.

What is the best query to delete the data? Or even just return a list of **RowID**'s that contain duplicates to be deleted (or the opposite, a list of **RowID**'s to be kept)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want's to delete record physically from the table or just ignore from the result set you want's to query

Comment: Delete them, otherwise I guess I could group by OrderId and Type :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a simple approach:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT min(rowid) FROM t
  GROUP BY orderid, type
)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c2c5/1).

Note that it seems you want to keep the lowers `rowid` when it is repeated. That's why I'm keeping the `min`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
Select Row_Number() Over(Partition BY ORDERID,TYPE ORDER BY RowId) as Rows,
RowId   ,  OrderId   ,  Type  ,   Text from TableName
)
Select RowId   ,  OrderId   ,  Type  ,   Text from cte where Rows>1
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e49d1/7)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
with c as
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by OrderId, Type order by (select 0)) as n
  from YourTable
)
delete from c
where n > 1;
```